# Getting text from TextBox in Windows Form and putting it into TextBox in Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am relatively new to programming in general - the last formal object oriented programming class I took was my freshman year of college (my jargon may not be accurate). So please, bear with me. If this question should be asked in a different area (such as the C# forum, please let me know).

Basically, the premise is this: in one solution I have two projects, a Windows Form Application and a Web Application. My Windows Form Application will be a simple GUI (it will get more complicated later but I wanted to started more simply to start) with a label prompting the user to input some text, a TextBox for the user to input the text, and a Submit button. Once the Submit button is pressed I want to pass whatever was typed into the TextBox to appear in a TextBox on a given webpage (this webpage will be part of a Web Application that already exists but for now I am just using a local host for debugging and getting concepts down).

I have already designed the form for the Windows Form Application and designed the web page (again simple with a label stating "Text Entered from GUI:" and a TextBox). So now I'm stuck. I've tried a couple of different things and tried searching for a similar problems but no such luck. I thought that I could implement a "using" namespace with the name of my Windows Form project (in the aspx.cs page) but when I run, it doesn't recognize the method I use...so I tried putting the method directly in the .aspx page but it doesn't like the namespace I've given (asked if I was missing an assembly reference...which I am not...).

I feel like I am making this more difficult than it needs to be and I am not sure where to go from here. If someone needs to look at my code I will post it - I would post it now but it is a bit of a hassle. The computer I am programming on is not allowed to be hooked up to the Internet, nor am I allowed to use devices such as thumb drives, so I will have to type it in by hand. However, I am willing to do this if it means I can get some answers!! Again, I am here to learn and seek advice so any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Also, a speedy response is ideal!

Oh! I am using Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5 and my Windows Form Application is written in C#.

Comment: Try storing it somewhere and loading it on the Web page.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Windows app? Why can't the user do it directly on an Web app in some `<input />`? If you want to "share code" between projects, then that code should be in a library so it can be reused (e.g. WinForms, Web, Mobile). Hth...

Comment: Basically the end product will be a GUI which will push something out (an image or real-time video of sorts) after the button is pushed. For us, the user will not prompt/we will not ask the user what they want. Rather, we will just give them what we want them to see...if this makes any sense.

Comment: So the "client" (what the user uses) is the WinForm and that WinForm will obtain something from some network location (e.g. web)?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: my original answer was ill-thought-out.  Here's what I should have said:

I haven't used ASP.NET, so the server side of my answer may be a bit vague.  Basically what  you need to do on the client side is create an HTTP GET URL (like "http://www.yoursite.com/yourWebApp/theFormPage?textboxText=foo") where one of the parameters is a field that tells the web page what to put in its text box.  Then you need to "execute" that URL using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will result in the URL being opened in your default browser.  The web page needs to read the parameter you passed and generate a form where the `value` attribute of the appropriate `input` tag is the value of the parameter you posted.

Further edit after reading some comments above:

If you want to push images etc. to a website you'll need an HTTP POST using HTTPRequest like the first version of my answer suggested. However, in that case the WinForms app would catch the response from the server, rather than the page being launched in a web browser. Then it would be up to the WinForms app to parse and make use of the response data. If I understand you, you want to use the WinForms app to partially or completely "fill out the form" on the web page. Better than that would be for the client app to completely bypass the web form, submitting data behind the scenes.

Comment: Ok, in theory I understand this, but I will have to do a little research to put it all together, and I will look at the link you provided...also, would the same type of process work if say I wanted to send a particular image or other file to the web page. I am merely starting with a text box because I thought it would be easiest! In my comment above, I state what my end product will ideally be. Thanks

Comment: Basically set up a hyperlink like http://mywebapp.com/page.aspx?tbtext=blah in your WinForms and then on your web app, in 'page.aspx.cs'(assuming this is C#) do  `mytextbox.text = Request.QueryString["tbtext"];` in the pageload event.